# too many values to unpack confusion matrix

Tags: python, unpack

trying to get a confusion matrix for a decision tree

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree)
print(tn, fp, fn, tp)

confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree)
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ---->
>   1 tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree)
>         2 print(tn, fp, fn, tp)
>         3
>         4 confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree)
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Comment: Maybe you should try printing the output of `confusion_matrix` (without unpacking) and see what its shape is. (i.e `print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree))`

Comment: Are you using `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix`? If so, `tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree)` won't work. That function returns one `array` object with the confusion matrix. Try `print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree))`

Answer (score 4):

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree).ravel()
print(tn, fp, fn, tp)

confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree)
```

Please try to add ".ravel()". For more information, Please share the problem what you are going to solve.

Comment: I did it but my data is a location-based social media data, the matrix size is 14500 * 14500.  this one returns array -> confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_tree)  however how can I calculate the performance matrices of this matrix? Thanks.

Comment: Should I code my own function to calculate the performance matrices ? I found this. 
https://towardsdatascience.com/confusion-matrix-and-class-statistics-68b79f4f510b

Answer (score 0):

The answer from yaho cho is correct but;

I would like to add,  that the standard way of using Confusion_matrix function from *sklearn* library is to pass true_labels at first position arguments and predicted labels at the second position, other wise you will miss interpret the results, and in worse cases one wouldn't even notice.

**Reference**:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html